# Gridview selected row show on top of gridview row automatically when i can search row

Tags: c#

When search row selected then selected row show on top of gridviewrow automatically with highlighted and previous data also show but selected row index change.

Question is i have 1000 rows data in gridview when I can serach 500 row so 500 row show on top of gridview row and other data also shown in gridview.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(txt_empc.Text))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
        //when search row selected then selected row show on top of gridviewrow
        //automatically with highlighted and previous data also show but selected
        //row index change
    }
}
```

Comment: "The Question Is What Is the Question"

Comment: I'm sorry but... what ?

Comment: question is i have 1000 rows data in gridview when i can serach 500 row so 500 row show on top of gridview row and other data also shown in gridview

Comment: sorry about my english my english is not good

Comment: how did you fill your grid view ? is it bonded to a data source or not?

Comment: do you want to sort selected rows?

Comment: yup data coming from database

Comment: saeed bai jab mai row serach ki wo ro apne index se uth kar gridview k top index pr aajae baaki data waise hi rehe

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : assign CurrentCell to founded line to get it the first shown

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
   if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(txt_empc.Text))
   {
      row.Selected = true;
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
      break;
   }
}
```

or with linq to be better :

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                             .Where(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(txt_empc.Text)))
{
  row.Selected = true;
  dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dgwDistinte.Grid.Rows[row.Index].Cells[0];
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code but it's not an optimized one optimized it yourself and let me know if you found a better solution it takes 10 minutes for me !:/:!

```
List<DataGridViewRow>selectedRows = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(txt_empc.Text))
                {
                    selectedRows.Add(row);
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
                    ////when search row selected then selected row show on top of gridviewrow automatically with highlighted and previous data also show but selected row index change
                }
                row.Selected = false;
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0,row);
                dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
            }
```

Comment: no more sorting algorithms is used in this solution for sorting matters you should use some other solution